# Kubernetes Helm: Helpers includes accessible in one file, but not another

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

In one directory are numerous files, there is a _helpers.tpl file as well as .yaml templates that we use to deploy different services. To simplify my issue and what I'm working with:

```
_helpers.tpl
backup.yaml
writer.yaml
```

There is a variable defined in the `_helpers.tpl` file that is accessible in `backup.yaml`, but the exact same line of code referring to the exact same variable in `writer.yaml` gives the following error:

```
Error: template: temp-chart/templates/template.yaml:8:23: executing "temp-chart/templates/template.yaml" at <include "account" .>: error calling include: template: no template "account" associated with template "gotpl"
```

I did not create this project, so I'm wondering if there was an error in the initial setup of the writer.yaml file or something was overlooked? Are there any steps required in configuring the helpers file or the templates that ensures they can access one another?

_helpers.tpl

```
{{- define "account" -}}
{{- if .Values.backup.account -}}
{{- .Values.backup.account-}}
{{- else -}}
{{- .Values.buildVals.accountId -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

backup.yaml and writer.yaml are identical:

```
account: {{ include "account" . }}
```

Comment: Including the relevant section of template would have been helpful. My wild guess is the `with` keyword changing the context of `.`.

Comment: I added the .tpl and relevant .yaml code

Comment: There is a space missing at the 3rd line in your _helpers.tpl. I assume it is a copy/paste error, but when i fixed it, both backup.yaml and writer.yaml could access the variable in my simple test (where these yamls contained the single line you pasted and with an additional values.yaml containing a value for backup.account). As @jordanm posted, there must be something in the templates breaking this, but there should be no additional steps required for _helpers.tpl to work.

Comment: Yes, that is a copy+paste error on my part. I feel like there is something in the process when creating the template .yaml files that was skipped/done incorrectly for the `writer.yaml` compared to the `backup.yaml` by the person who set everything up (and no longer with the company). Only because the two .yaml files are referencing the _helpers.tpl in an identical way.

Comment: @Lennac and there is no `{{ with ... }}` anywhere above your posted line from backup.yaml?

Comment: There is not. I found the solution in a separate config somewhere entirely different in the repo where these components are apparently "configured". backup.yaml had the helpers path configured, the writer.yaml did not. I have no idea why. Or why the config in this other area of the repo is in charge of these components, but... there it is.